# jarInputstream in Jython

Tags: jython

I would like to know if the jarInputstream exists or can be use in Jython?
   thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
from java.net      import URL
from java.util.jar import JarInputStream

jar_location = "file:///usr/share/java/libgcj-4.4.jar"
inStream = JarInputStream(URL(jar_location).openStream(), True)

# print an entry with max size
entry = max(iter(inStream.getNextJarEntry, None), key=lambda entry: entry.size)
print entry.name, entry.size
```

#### Output

```
gnu/javax/net/ssl/StaticTrustAnchors.class 92341
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

I try to do this but I obtain this : 
    
    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500

maybe because the jar location is a http address.

does jar_location only for a file?

Comment: The error happen when I want to do this:
inStream = JarInputStream(URL(jar_location).openStream(), True)

Comment: Finally I find my mistake, in fact I can't use the openStream. So I need to find another way to do it.

Comment: @tranen: http error 500 means there is a problem on the server. `jar_location` can be `http://..` url (in that case use `inStream.read()` to make `entry.size` return anything but `-1`).